# pull HTML from XML file based on correct user string

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to make part of a html page only accessible via a code.  The page is written in pure html / css / javascript.

The logic is this:

1. User enters a string into a form
2. An xmlHttpRequest is sent when the submit button is clicked to see if this string matches the correct code
3. If it does, another xmlHttpRequest is sent to get the HTML for the secret part of the page.

The question is:  how do I prevent the user from simply examining the javascript code and being able to look at the xml files based on their file names?

Is this possible with pure ajax or do I actually have to user a server-side script to verify the code?

EDIT: Also, if I *do* have to use a server-side script, what's the cleanest, simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. In point 2. you say that you use AJAX request to verify password - so you are already making request to server where server-side script is checking code. At this point if server checks that password is correct you can simply send secret part of the page back to the browser.

EDIT: So I think you already answered your own question - you need to write a server side script.

Comment: Thanks - I just don't fully understand how this works. I write a php program which verifies the string to be correct. This is fine. But I don't want to return an entire php page.  I want to pull a partial html page from an xml file.  Where I'm unsure is how php and ajax are supposed to communicate with each other to achieve this

Comment: AJAX is only a normal request to server. Your ajax script needs to send parameter which will tell server it wants only a part of the page. Your php script/framework checks for parameter and if it's set then sends just a part of page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a server-side script, but since you're using a form you actually don't need javascript or AJAX at all. The form will send the password to a php script which will verify it and return the html page if it's correct. Here's an example:

HTML in main page:

```
<iframe src="login.html"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

HTML in login.html:

```
<form action="secretpage.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP in secretpage.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['pass']=="mypassword")
{
 echo "<p>This is the secret part of the html page.</p>";
}
else
{
 echo "<p>Incorrect password.</p>";
}
?>
```